# По нажатию на кнопку менять блок

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть 2 кнопки, "Красноярск" и "Красноярский край". Нужно чтобы по нажатию на кнопку менялась карта на сайте. Как это реализовать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какую карту Вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Добавил картинку, как нужно сделать.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function(){
$(".knopka-1").click(function(){
  $(".block-2").fadeOut(1);
  $(".block-1").fadeIn(100);
  });
  $(".knopka-2").click(function(){
  $(".block-1").fadeOut(1);
  $(".block-2").fadeIn(100);
  });
  });
```

```css
.block-1 {
  padding: 40px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  }

.block-2 {
  padding: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: none;
  }

.knopka {
  margin-top: 30px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="big-block">
<div class="block-1">Блок 1</div>
<div class="block-2">Блок 2</div>
<button class="knopka-1">кнопка 1</button>
  <button class="knopka-2">кнопка 2</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Джаваскриптом вешаешь слушатели на клик на обе кнопки. В обоих слушателях изменяешь аттрибут `src` у картинки на нужный

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы и надписи с иконками тоже были в других местах, соответствующих, так как карта будет другая. По сути нужно менять весь блок.

Comment: Смотри, тебе в самом начале сказали, что ифны недостаточно, чтобы ответить вопрос, тебе пришлось прикрепить скрин. Теперь оказывается, что иконки и надписи - не являются частью карты (это не очевидно). Может ты сразу всю картину опишешь? Тратишь свое время и время других пользователей

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте два блока, один скрытый (через свойство hidden).
При нажатии на кнопку тот, который скрытый, делаете видимым. А второй - наоборот скрываете.